# Выдает ошибку в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вот такую ошибку выдает Юнити что делать

> Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(44,12): error CS1061: 'Rigidbody' does not
> contain a definition for 'AddForse' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddForse' accepting a first argument of type 'Rigidbody' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
 
    public float runSpeed = 500f; 
    public float strafeSpeed = 500f;
    public float jumpForse = 15f;
 
    protected bool strafeLeft = false;
    protected bool strafeRight = false;
    protected bool doJump = false;
     
 
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            strafeLeft = true;
        } else
        {
            strafeLeft = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            strafeRight = true;
        } else
        {
            strafeRight = false;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            doJump = true;
        } else
        {
            doJump = false;
        }
    }
 
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForse(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);  //Тут ошибка
    }
}
```

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, воткните зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
rb.AddForse(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

на

```
rb.AddForсe(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое просто только начал учить

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог - не затруднитесь отметить его как верный

Comment: У нас же вроде есть определенная причина для закрытия: `Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям`. Правила сайта не рекомендуют отвечать на подобные вопросы...

Comment: Если обращаетесь к собеседнику, не забывайте указывать, к какому именно, иначе он не получит уведомление - @nummary. Исключение - если вы обращаетесь к автору поста, то тегать собеседника не нужно.